# Part of the function code isn't executed

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a simple web app in javascript for a school project. It seems to be easy, but when I call a function not all lines of code are executed. It seems to stop after the `for` cicle. In fact nothing happens after the click on button.

```
function calcola(){
    var texts = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    var ang;
    var v;
    var h;
    for (var i=0;i<texts.length+selects.length;i++) {
            if (selects[i].id == 'a') {
                ang = selects[i].value;
            }
            if (selects[i].id == 'v') {
                v = selects[i].value;   
            }
            if (texts[i].id == 'h') {
                h = texts[i].value;
            }
    }
    var vy0 = v*Math.sin(ang*(Math.PI/180));
    var t1 = vy0/9.81;
    var h1 = (vy0*t1)/2;
    var ht = h + h1;
    var t2 = Math.pow((2*ht)/9.81,0.5);
    var tt = t1 + t2;
    var vx0 = v*Math.cos(ang*(Math.PI/180));
    var x = vx0*tt;
    document.body.innerHTML = "<center style='font-size: 4.5em; font-family: monospace'>Distanza percorsa: " + Math.round(x*100)/100 + " m</center><br><center style='font-size: 4.5em; font-family: monospace'>Velocita' Iniziale: " + v + " m/s</center><br><center style='font-size: 4.5em; font-family: monospace'>Angolazione: " + a + "&deg;</center><br><center style='font-size: 4.5em; font-family: monospace'>Newton Di Spinta: " + "..." + " N</center>";
}
```

Comment: Look at the console.

Comment: PLEASE POST RELATED HTML CODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping over the total number of "texts" and "selects" (texts.length+selects.length) - which is almost certainly going to result in an array out-of-bounds error when you index using i.

You probably want minimum:

```
for (var i=0;i<Math.min(texts.length,selects.length);i++) {...
```

or two separate loops to iterate over each of the  elements and the  elements.